# Complex SQL query

Tags: oracle, t-sql, sql

There is a customer table. I want to list active and inactive status in one query. How can I do this?

```
SELECT count(*) as ACTIVE, 
count(*) as INACTIVE 
FROM V_CUSTOMER 
WHERE STATUS='a' AND STATUS='i'
```

Comment: wonder y wrong answer get selected ?

Comment: I just need one query not one row. Thanks everyone

Comment: it seems that question is not clear

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using group by:

```
SELECT count(*), STATUS FROM V_CUSTOMER
Where STATUS='a' OR STATUS='d'
GROUP BY STATUS
```

Comment: this will count all recods active + deactive but i think he need seprate count of active and deactive

Comment: @Jack - this solution returns two rows whereas the solution proposed by Pranay will give you the two counts in a single row, which is want you asked for.

Comment: @APC, OP asked for one query not one row, IMO this solution would be easy to maintain if for instance you wanted to include another status or remove the where clause and get count for each status.

Comment: Well, I still think Pranay's solution is th ecloser to what was requested (it was the one I would have supplied if I had been a fatser typist).  As for maintainability, YAGNI applies to SQL statements as much as any other code.  We should strive for the most appropriate solution for now, and not worry about putative future requirements until they materialize.

Answer (score 5):

We can use CASE statement to translate the two values of STATUS:

```
SELECT 
    sum(case when STATUS = 'a' then 1 else 0 end) as ACTIVE 
    , sum(case when STATUS = 'd' then 1 else 0 end) as DEACTIVE 
FROM V_CUSTOMER
```

There is no need for a WHERE clause unless there are a large number of records with other values for STATUS, in which case use `OR` instead of `AND`:

```
WHERE STATUS='a' OR STATUS='d'
```

Comment: I think `case when` is sql server, not oracle?

Comment: @StefanSteinegger - Oracle has supported CASE in SELECT statements since 8i (i.e. for more than a decade)

Comment: +1 I prefer this solution because it is the closest to the OP's request, as it returns a single row.

Comment: @pranay: sorry, didn't know that. Who's "wrong answer had been selected"?

Comment: @pranay, as I have stated you have misread the question if you consider my answer wrong.  OP wanted the result in one *query*, **not** one *row*.  The amount of rows that is returned is inconsequential.

Comment: @krock no problem -- anyway tanks -- its ok

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT count(decode(status,'a',1)) as ACTIVE, 
count(decode(status,'d',1)) as DEACTIVE 
FROM V_CUSTOMER 
WHERE STATUS='a' or STATUS='d'
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll need something like this:

```
select Status, count(*) from V_Customer
where STATUS='a' or STATUS='d'
group by STATUS
```

This will give you the number of records per status.